# VSCode java app launch failed with externalTerminal

Tags: java, macos, shell, visual-studio-code

how can I launch a spring boot app from VSCode with `"terminal.external.osxExec": "Terminal.app"` or better `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"` ?

All my attempts failed due to VSCode cut the command line after 1024 chars and the message `Failed to launch debuggee in terminal. Reason: com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException`is shown.

If I use those settings mentioned in the VSCode docs, VSCode launches the external process. The window (terminal or iterm) shows the usually welcome lines (Last Login ... / You have mail .. etc.) Then the first 1024 chars of a kind of command line VSCode uses to start the application are shown. But due to environment variables, 1024 chars are far too little for the whole command. VSCode can use the `@argfile` settings for modern java cmd's but, those argfiles contains arguments for the java application itself. This is not the problem here... it's the amount of the ENVs. The maximum length limit on my command line is 262144 chars determined with `echo "%$(getconf ARG_MAX)s"`.

If I should reduce the amount of environment variables, how VSCode determine, which ENVs are used for the startup command line ? I've tried to reduce the ENVs used by the Terminal.app to under 1024 chars. Then I started code from within this shell by using `code` with . But every subsequent launch of my application under development from within VSCode with settings `"terminal.external.osxExec": "Terminal.app",` uses the Terminal.app but with different ENVs, not those one I've set before ?

Comment: If you want to debug the project in external terminal, set `"console": "externalTerminal"` in launch.json should work.

Comment: Thank you for your time to respond. But my settings mentioned above do only work if `"console":"externalTerminal"`And only in this case (compared to `"console":"integratedTerminal"` and `"console":"internalConsole"`) my problem occur.

Comment: Can't reproduce your question, can you record a gif to show the error?